# LM317 using 2N2222 as current limit

Tags: current-limiting, lm317

I am trying to build a current limiting circuit using LM317.
The goal is to limit output current to ~150mA with 25V input and output at >20V.

I built the circuit according to ST datasheet, using the circuit diagram in Figure 13, page 12 as a base model, changed R1 to 120ohm, R2: 2200ohm, R3: 4.7ohm, in LTspice, I successfully simulated the current cut off at around 150mA with a maximum DC output at ~23VDC.

But the actual circuit is limited at a maximum DC output of ~10V.
What is going on?

EDIT: Turns out the Q1 diode I used was inverted. See comments from @BruceAbbott

[image: schematic of circuit]
[image: simulated current cut off in LTspice]

Reference: [ST LM317 datasheet, figure 13 on page 12](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm217.pdf)

Comment: perhaps 10 V is the voltage required to produce the 150 mA output current

Comment: Perhaps thermal shutdown 15V drop @150mA=2.25W * 50'C/W +20'C=133'C

Comment: possibly C2 bad or R2 low or R4 high

Comment: Is the transistor connected correctly? http://www.analogzoo.com/2015/03/beware-the-p2n222a/

Comment: What really happens when you short the output?

Comment: With the schematic values you have, short circuit current will be about 250mA since the lowest output from the LM317 is 1.2V. With an input of 20V that results in about 4.75W power dissipation in the LM317. How big a heatsink do you have?

Comment: mistaken  R values ?

Comment: OP is non-responsive. Oh, well.

Comment: @BruceAbbott The pn2222a vs the p2n2222a is something I've kept in mind as long as the parts have existed. I got caught exactly once by it. (Very cheap batch of NPNs but with an unfamiliar pinout, as I soon learned.) Never again.

Comment: @jonk He may sleep occasionally and live in a far off place time-zone-relatively.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yeah. But when I wrote that, we were three hours in. And I was an hour late in arriving, already. So nothing for the first two hours. I suppose he could just launch a question, go to bed, and wake up to a cup of coffee and fresh answers. Just a batch AI system that runs in the background.  ;)

Comment: To troubleshoot the circuit, I removed all capacitors and protection diodes, leaving only R1, R2, R4 and R5. LM317 is left without a heatsink. The 10V output isn't caused by thermal shutdown. I will try shorting the output and report back. But I have a feeling that Q1 is having an equivalent resistance of around 2Kohm, when in parallel with R2, making the adj resistor of effectively 1Kohm, therefore maximum output voltage is 10V.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, you are correct. I used 2N2222A, where the pinout I took was from a P2N2222A datasheet.